# I have a String like this "6:45AM" then how can i convert it into 24-hour TimeOfDay or DateTime format

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert a string (12 hour) "6:45PM" into a 18:45:00 (24 hour) TimeOfDay Format, how can be this done?

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far and what exactly was wrong with that?

Comment: @Secespitus Hello I have seen the document of TimeOfDay class but not got any method for converting such string into 24 format

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try to use a DateFormat, just include intl dependency to your pubspec.yaml

First parse the value to a date, then format it how you want

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
// parse date
DateTime date= DateFormat.jm().parse("6:45 PM");
DateTime date2= DateFormat("hh:mma").parse("6:45PM"); // think this will work better for you
// format date
print(DateFormat("HH:mm").format(date));
print(DateFormat("HH:mm").format(date2));
```

References

- [DateTime](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html)
- [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but in between the 45 and PM there should be a space, but for my string there is no space in between

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 var df =  DateFormat("h:mma");
 var dt = df.parse('6:45PM');
 print(DateFormat('HH:mm').format(dt));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this format:

```
DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of "hh:mm:ssPM" or "hh:mm:ssAM" -

```
String [] splitedString = yourString.split(":");
String newFormat = splitedString[2].contain("PM") ? String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(splitedString[0]) + 12) : splitedString[0] + ":" + splitedString[1] + ":" + splitedString[2].substring(0,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `TimeOfDay` you can easily convert it into 24 hour by using the following code

```
TimeOfDay? selectedTime = TimeOfDay.now();

var replacingTime = selectedTime!.replacing(
                            hour: selectedTime!.hour,
                            minute: selectedTime!.minute);

String formattedTime = replacingTime.hour.toString() +
                                ":" +
                                replacingTime.minute.toString();
```

this worked for me.