# How i Can convert 12 hour time string into 24 hour in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have a 12 hour formatted String like 02:00 p.m. i want to convert it into 24 hour time format like 14:00:00.

Comment: Check out this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109313/i-have-a-string-like-this-645am-then-how-can-i-convert-it-into-24-hour-timeof

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a String like this "6:45AM" then how can i convert it into 24-hour TimeOfDay or DateTime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57109313/i-have-a-string-like-this-645am-then-how-can-i-convert-it-into-24-hour-timeof)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package to your pubspec yaml

Then import the package in your dart file

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

You have to pass value as DateTime to format method from DateFormat class in intl package

```
DateTime newDateTime = DateTime.parse(dateTimeString);
String formattedTime = DateFormat('dd MMM yy, HH:mm').format(newDateTime);
```

You can view the available DateFormats in this [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the intl package https://pub.dev/packages/intl
here is the documentation for the class u need https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have dateTime or TimeOfDay type you can use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package, otherwise here is my workaround.

```
String time12to24Format(String time) {
// var time = "12:01 AM";
 int h = int.parse(time.split(":").first);
 int m = int.parse(time.split(":").last.split(" ").first);
 String meridium = time.split(":").last.split(" ").last.toLowerCase();
  if (meridium == "pm") {
   if (h != 12) {
     h = h + 12;
   }
 }
 if (meridium == "am") {
   if (h == 12) {
     h = 00;
   }
 }
 String newTime = "${h == 0 ? "00" : h}:${m == 0 ? "00" : m}";
 print(newTime);

 return newTime;
}
```